# React and mobx - events?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have a React app with Mobx.

This is my problem:

I hava a sidebar that clicks on a button should invoke methods of another component (the observer). If the sidebar changes a value in the store - all is fine. I have defined a mobx.reaction an I can easily invoke the method

But what should I do if I just want to invoke a method - like reset or init? no value should be changed in the store.

How can I do that?

Regards,
Ido

Comment: When should this method be invoked?

Comment: Lets say button click on the sidebar

Comment: So just call the method without changing anything in the store

Comment: But how will the logic in the observer will be invoked?

Comment: You need to move the logic out of observer and observer can call the new function and you event handler can call it too